# Does SharePoint 2013 file search favour Microsoft documents over PDFs?

Tags: search-results

I have a Content Source which crawls a network folder containing Word, PowerPoint and PDF documents. I have in addition a Result Source based directly on this content source and a Search Results web part which uses the Result Source as its query. If I search for “Digital Cameras” the first result is a PowerPoint document entitled “Digital Cameras: Thriving Amidst a Declining Market.” However, there is a PDF file also in the directory with the exact same title, but this file does not appear unless I filter by PDF Result Type, at which point it appears at the top of the list. In fact, with Result Type set to All, I cannot see the PDF version of the file even if I click through all the pages of the initial search.

I thought it might be considered a duplicate but I have “Show View Duplicates” checked and “Trim Duplicates” set to false. The pop-out next to the initial search item does not show a duplicate. The PDFs are definitely being crawled because otherwise they would not appear at all, no matter what the filtering.

How do I get the PDF document to appear in the basic search next to the PowerPoint document with the same title?

Answer (score 0):

To your question, the answer is No (It is a setting).

Try going to **Site Settings**, under Search, **Result Types**. See if PDF is part of the priority sequence given here. If not, you can add a new result type for PDF. Which content type appears before or after is set by the priority given on this page, which you can configure.

Also, verify the same for site collection level, by clicking **Manage site collection result types** (it is to the far right of the new result type action).

Comment: Hi, the Result Types in Site Settings show "PDF with Preview" as the first two items.  I have put an image of my initial search here: 
http://i.imgur.com/dx2Hw5D.png
And of the filtered search here:
http://i.imgur.com/vPBKDOL.png

Comment: "PDF with Preview"? that isn't an OOTB result type. Were the result types customized? If so, check the result type itself to see if there were any special criteria specified.